# Defining a dynamic JavaScript global in PSI

Tags: intellij-plugin

I'm a bit new to IntelliJ plugin development and I'm looking for a clean way to define a new JavaScript global constant whose value is dynamically computed from the contents of a file.

More specifically, I'm not sure which API point I should use and whether I should implement this directly by injecting data into the JS files' PSI, or if I should use one of [WebStorm's JavaScript-specific API entry points](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/webstorm-extension-point-list.html#javascript). I would have liked to read the source code of CommonJS' `require()` handler but it's part of the closed-source built-in "JavaScript and TypeScript" plugin.

I've found potential candidates but the IntelliJ plugin API is incredibly poorly documented:

- predefinedLibraryProvider: is that really used to define a global value?
- psi.referenceContributor: is this used to define the value of a "PSIReference" element or just a way to add entries to "Go to references"?
- resolveHelper: the name sounds nice, but I'm not sure it really allows me to customize name resolution
- File load listener + injection into PSI (not sure if that's possible): seems pretty dirty

I insist on the fact that the global value is dynamically computed, so I can't just inject a `.d.ts` in the file and call it a day. The value would obviously be cached though. I would like to work at the highest level possible so I don't have to touch too many APIs to get good integration with existing tooling.

Thanks in advance.